# Apache httpd, starts but failed. Fedora 19 and webmin

Tags: apache, webmin

I have a problem start apache from webmin, it works but webmin not registre it's running. And the log shows this failed.

In running procsses it work, and the testpages running on the server.

Fedora 19
Apache version 2.4.6
Webmin 1.660

What to do. please help?

```
---------------LOG----------------
Failed to start apache : Apache does not appear to be running :
[Thu Dec 05 23:57:56.773010 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4712] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Thu Dec 05 23:57:56.774357 2013] [suexec:notice] [pid 4712] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Dec 05 23:57:56.860940 2013] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 4712] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Dec 05 23:57:56.975651 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4712] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips PHP/5.5.6 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 05 23:57:56.975690 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4712] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```